# Similarities between spaces X and Y using their homotopy/homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

im still relatively new to Algebraic Topology, so bear with potential wrong statements.

After finding out about Whiteheads Theorem, i was wondering on what results we can get for general topological spaces X and Y, if we compare their homotopy groups and homoloy groups. Assume we have

$\pi_n(X)\cong \pi_n(Y) $

and

$H_n(X) \cong H_n(Y)$

such that they are isomorphic for all $n\geq 0$, can we conclude anything about them? If i understand correctly we can neither conclude homotopy equivalence nor homeomorphic equivalence. What can we say about the Spaces $X$ and $Y$? Is there even any general result/similarity that we can observe if the upper condition holds? Are there any conditions that must be satisfied, so that they become homotopy equivalent?

Maybe someone knows some texts where this is discussed already (it most certainly is) in great detail.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of not having to worry about basepoints, let's assume that $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected. If $\pi_n(X) \cong \pi_n(Y)$ and $H_n(X) \cong H_n(Y)$ for all $n$ but the hypotheses of Whitehead's theorem don't apply — that is, it is not known that there is a map inducing these isomorphisms — then I think that we can conclude nothing about similarities between $X$ and $Y$ that don't just correspond to homology or homotopy group information. (For example, they have the same Euler characteristic, if it's defined for these spaces, because it's defined in terms of homology groups.)

First, plenty of topological information — compactness and dimension, for example — is not homotopy invariant and so are not detectable using just $\pi_n$ and $H_n$. By just considering these groups, you are losing topological information. Second, there are examples of spaces with the same homotopy and homology groups but which are not homotopy equivalent. So you are also losing homotopy theoretic information. Third, if they are not CW complexes, even if there is a map inducing the isomorphisms, it need not have a homotopy inverse: the spaces need not be homotopy equivalent.

You ask, "Are there any conditions that must be satisfied, so that they become homotopy equivalent?" That's precisely what Whitehead's theorem answers. There are also a few special cases. For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes and have exactly one nonzero homotopy group, then they are homotopy equivalent. But in general Whitehead's theorem is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! So without making any substantial assumptions/obeservations on X and Y beforehand, simply comparing their homotopy/homology groups doesnt give us any more information than what we already got, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.